# Javascript function in anchor() not working properly in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a page *settings.php* in codeigniter whose controller is *member.php*. I have a link '*Movie Settings*' in settings.php and on clicking it I want to show a div and hide another div.

In *settings.php*, I have this line:

```
<?php echo anchor('member/settings', 'Movie Settings', array('onClick' => "moviesetting()"));
```

**settings.php**

```
<div class="mainsettingdiv">
    <div class="leftsettingdiv">
        Profile Settings
        <br>
        <?php echo anchor('member/settings', 'Movie Settings', array('onClick' => "moviesetting()"));

        ?>
    </div>

    <div class="rightsettingdiv" id="profilediv">
        <b>Profile Image Visibility</b> <br>
        <?php echo form_radio('imageset','1')?> Public 
        <?php echo form_radio('imageset','2')?> Friends Only
        <?php echo form_radio('imageset','3')?> Private

        <br><br>
        <b>Email Visibility</b> <br>
        <?php echo form_radio('emailset','1')?> Public 
        <?php echo form_radio('emailset','2')?> Friends Only
        <?php echo form_radio('emailset','3')?> Private

        <br><br>
        <b>Address Visibility</b> <br>
        <?php echo form_radio('addressset','1')?> Public 
        <?php echo form_radio('addressset','2')?> Friends Only
        <?php echo form_radio('addressset','3')?> Private

        <br><br>
        <b>Mobile Number Visibility</b> <br>
        <?php echo form_radio('mobileset','1')?> Public 
        <?php echo form_radio('mobileset','2')?> Friends Only
        <?php echo form_radio('mobileset','3')?> Private
        <br>

        <?php
        $js = 'onClick="saveprofilesetting('.$id.',\''.base_url().'\')"';
        echo form_button('save','Save',$js);?>
    </div>

    <div class="moviesettings" style="display:none" id="moviediv">

    </div>

</div>
```

and my javascript function:

```
function moviesetting()
{ 
    $("#moviediv").show();
    $("#profilediv").hide();
}
```

But as I am using `anchor()` the page is getting reloaded on clicking. So the javascript function is not seem to be worked. How can I remove the href from the `anchor()` and make it work?

I tried with adding `#` and `javascript:void(0)` in `anchor()`, but in both cases it is getting redirected to index page. I don't want redirection. Can anyone help me to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're specifying a route as the first argument (Although this is OK, but you need to preventDefault in your javascript) OR just use '#' instead of the route 'member/settings'

Answer (score 1):

Add `return false;` in your js function to avoid page reload

```
function moviesetting()
{ 
    $("#moviediv").show();
    $("#profilediv").hide();
    return false;
}
```

Comment: you mean as pure html?

Comment: did you do any changes apart from my answer?

Comment: no just replaced anchor() with <a onclick="moviesetting()">Movie Settings</a>